# Account id is not available to select in process builder

Tags: process-builder, salesforce-id, person-accounts

I've created a process builder on Account object. I need to select Id field from the immediate actions. That action is to launch a flow. But Id field is not available in the field picklist.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that, Go with record-triggered flow.
Salesforce itself is suggesting to use Flows over ProcessBuilders.
That means they are planning to shut down ProcessBuilders in near future.

Comment: Yes, instead of triggering a Process Builder and invoke a flow from there, you can try record-triggered flow. You can refer to the following links for considerations for record-trigger flow approach. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/winter-21-release-highlights-no-code/get-hands-on-with-a-record-triggered-flow
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_trigger_record.htm&type=5